# Mostrar "gif cargando" mientras la ventana carga

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de mostrar un gif o un bar progress mientras la ventana está cargando con un status **"pending"**.

He utilizado el método ***window.onload = function() ...*** pero solo me funciona al cargar los datos, necesito un metodo que ejecute mi gif mientras la ventana carga, es decir, que al mismo tiempo que la ventana del navegador muestre que esta cargando mi gif también.

**PD:** No adjunto nada de código porque básicamente usé el ***window.onload = function() ...*** como mencioné anteriormente.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/452925/54039) seguramente te servirá.

Answer (score 0):

El evento `windows.onload` se ejecuta recién cuando la página termina de cargarse, con lo cual puede servirte para quitar el indicador de carga pero no para mostrarlo. Una posibilidad puede ser la siguiente: utilizar los eventos de `document` ([ver documentación y ejemplos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event)) para mostrar el elemento deseado con `readystatechange`, y luego quitarlo con `load`. No será simultáneo al indicador de carga del navegador, porque parte de la página necesita ser interactiva para ejecutar el código, solo será útil si el tiempo de carga es relativamente extenso.

Si puedas optar, te recomendaría no usar un indicador de carga, simplemente mostrar la página lo más rápido posible al usuario.